# Display C++ program in Java

Tags: java, c++, swing, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI and just started learning it.

I have successfully executed a `graphical C++ program` in java using `JNI`. Now i want to try something more advanced which is **display that C++ graphical program within JFrame or JPanel.**

Is it possible and how to do it ? Ideally it would be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57TLu.png)

Thanks for answering and sorry if my question is vague.

**Edit** : This is quite similiar to my question [Display a C++ window in a java GUI](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/132121-display-c-window-java-gui)

Comment: The C++ program will, at some level, be making calls to interact directly with the native graphics environment.  You would probably have to do a substantial rewrite of the C++ code to get it to interact with the Java objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically that should be possible, although not with JFrame/JPanel. Swing is peerless, and you'd have to use a heavyweight component as the parent for your UI. But everything you do there is highly not-portable and it involves JRE internal classes, so if you really get this done it might break with another JRE version. And you might run into weird problems with event handling.

As a starter you could look at what the Eclipse SWT_AWT bridge is doing. Essentially they're doing what you describe, embed something that's not AWT in an AWT Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution from [Embed OpenGL inside Java AWT Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791/Embed-OpenGL-inside-Java-AWT-Canvas).
Someone please correct me  if this is not related.

Thank you Jim and user2543253 for your help.