# How to embed c++ open GL window in jframe or jpanel

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I and my team are developing a 3d simulation software in java,We did most of the work but would like to do the 3d simulation in c++ so we would have to append the c++ window in our java swing application.I'm familiar with java,c/c++ and JNI.We would be glad for your help.

Comment: Show us what you did so far – aka "Da Code?"

Comment: You can only embed in an AWT canvas because Swing (J*) components are lightweight. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979052/display-c-program-in-java links to an article about embedding http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791/Embed-OpenGL-inside-Java-AWT-Canvas . Didn't read it myself, however.